# Linked Lists Struct in C. Altering shared element in only one list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have these structs in C:

```
typedef struct team{
    char *name;
    int wins;
} *pTeam;

typedef struct node_team{
    pTeam team;
    struct node_team *next;
} *link_team;
```

So I have various of these teams, and I'm putting them on a linked list, each element of the linked list is a link_team, so having 2 link_team's, `A` and `B`, if I want to put `B` after `A`, I do `A->next=B`. However, I have 2 lists, and both lists share some of the same elements, and so if I have `A` in both of them and want `B` after `A` in one list, I don't want it in the other list. However, since we're talking about pointers, and both lists have the pointer pointing to the struct `A`, by doing `A->next=B` in one list, `B` is linked to `A` automatically in the other list as well. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Answer (score 0):

The `next` pointers are what make the linked list a linked list.  So, you couldn't mix the lists the way you're doing it.  However, the only data a node contains besides the pointer to the next object is the `pTeam` object.  That can easily be shared across different lists (though you need to be careful).

```
... // Suppose you already have five pTeam pointers: p1, ..., p5

link_team *head1, *head2, *node1, *node2, *node3, *node4;

head1=malloc(sizeof(*link_team));
head2=malloc(sizeof(*link_team)); // I should be checking these return values but oh well.

head1->team=p1;
head2->team=p2;

node1=malloc(sizeof(*link_team));
node1->team=p3;
head1->next=node1;

node2=malloc(sizeof(*link_team));
node2->team=p3;
head2->next=node2;

node3=malloc(sizeof(*link_team));
node3->team=p4;
node3->next=NULL;
node1->next=node3;

node4=malloc(sizeof(*link_team));
node4->team=p5;
node4->next=NULL;
node2->next=node4;
```

Comment: I see, so in my original exemple, if I want A in both lists, I'd inevitably need to use a second malloc, one malloc for each list (not counting with mallocs for future elements, like B for exemple)

Comment: The danger you can run into, however, is forgetting that nodes in different lists contain pointers to the same `pTeam` objects.  Therefore, if you free one pointer and try to use the other, you're going to crash with a segfault.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, that is a very important aspect to look out for, thanks!

Comment: @iugubhk, if you found my answer useful, feel free to upvote it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers